# How to retrieve posts of a user that is selected from a tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xcode8

I am having troubles trying to retrieve posts of a user that is previously selected from a tableview. I am able to retrieve a users info such as name, profile pic etc, but I'm having difficulty retrieving their posts. At the moment my code is not returning anything. I've posted my code below. Where I'm having the issue is in the `guestPhotoViewController` where I call the function `loadUserPosts()`. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
tableview controller

 @IBOutlet weak var searchTableView: UITableView!
var profiles = [user]()
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

override func viewdidload(){
 ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "guestSegue", sender: self)
    self.searchTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "guestSegue" {

        if let indexpath = searchTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

            let tabBarController = segue.destination as! UITabBarController


            let guestVC = tabBarController.viewControllers![0] as! guestProfileViewController


            _ = tabBarController.viewControllers![1] as! guestPhotoViewController


            _ = tabBarController.viewControllers![2] as! guestVideoViewController


            guestVC.ref = profiles[indexpath.row].ref

              print(indexpath)

            }
        }
    }
```

guestPhotoViewController - which is where I'm trying to retrieve posts from firebase

```
class guestPhotoViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundProfileImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: roundImage!

    @IBOutlet weak var fullNameLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var postCell: UITableViewCell!

    @IBOutlet weak var postTableView: UITableView!


var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

var posts = [Post]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    loadUserPosts()

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

}

func loadUserPosts(){

if let ref = ref {


   let postsRef = ref.child("post")


    postsRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                for post in snapshot.children {

                    let post = Post(snapshot: post as! FIRDataSnapshot)

                    self.posts.append(post)

                print(post)
                self.postTableView.reloadData()

            }
        })
    }

}
```

posts array

```
class Post{
    var profilePic: String!
    var fullName: String!
    var postImage: String!
    var postCaption: String!
    var date: NSNumber!

init(profilePic: String, fullName:String, postImage:String, postCaption: String, date:NSNumber){
    self.profilePic = profilePic
    self.fullName = fullName
    self.postImage = postImage
    self.postCaption = postCaption
    self.date = date
}

init(snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) {
    self.profilePic = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["profilePic"] as! String!
    self.date = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["dateOfPost"] as! NSNumber!
    self.fullName = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["fullName"] as! String!
    self.postImage = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["postedPic"] as! String!
    self.postCaption = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["postCaption"] as! String!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1: If you override, remember to call `super.method` when it applies.

2: It's not very clear if what fails is the request *or* the updating of a tableview to display the data.

Also, in `guestPhotoViewController` you seem to be calling `loadUserPosts` *before* setting the reference. Shouldn't you be doing that in reverse? first set the reference and then make the request? Otherwise your `if let ref = ref` will always fail.

Edit: As for your new problem, it seems to be an issue about how to filter the data you retrieve. Or, in this case, how you are **not** filtering it.

Try something like this (adapted to your needs)

In your `tableViewVC`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Name", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vcIdentifier") as! YourViewController
    vc.prepareVC(withId: indexPath.row)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

In your `guestPhotoViewController`

```
class guestPhotoViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundProfileImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: roundImage!
    @IBOutlet weak var fullNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var postCell: UITableViewCell!
    @IBOutlet weak var postTableView: UITableView!
    private var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
    private var posts = [Post]()
    private var posterId: Int = -1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        loadUserPosts()
    }

    func prepareVC(withId: id) {
        self.posterId = id
    }

    func loadUserPosts(){
        if self.id != -1 {
            if let ref = ref {
                /*  Probably something around here is messed up. You don't seem to be filtering by id, just retrieving "post".
                    You might want to consider checking how you filter (you don't seem to do so at all) the postRef, since that seems to be the issue.
                    I don't know your FireBase models, so it's harder to help you with that.
                */
                let postsRef = ref.child("post").equalTo(self.posterId)
                /*
                 or if they are ordered, you can use:
                 let postsRef = ref.queryOrderedByChild("post").queryEqualToValue(self.posterId)
                */
                postsRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    for post in snapshot.children {
                        let post = Post(snapshot: post as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                        self.posts.append(post)
                        print(post)
                        self.postTableView.reloadData()
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AleRavasio. Your right I accidentally called loadUserPost before the ref so I changed it but now I have a problem because it loads the posts of every user not just the posts of a user you select. I'm not sure how to code in a way that only calls for the posts of a user you select from the previous tableview. could you please help me? I used a similar call method to retrieve other info and it worked. Im new to the coding world so excuse me if things don't make sense

Comment: I tried updating my code with what you had written but I'm not getting any luck. I'm getting errors with the index and also with prepareVC init. I added a reference in my Posts array but still having troubles trying to retrieve the right posts. In Firebase I have it setout as  "post". child(userID).child(postID) if that helps you understand it bit better @AleRavasio